# Proof verification: If $gf$ is surjective and $g$ is injective, then $f$ is surjective

Tags: functions, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

*Proof.* Let $f:A\rightarrow B$ and $g:B\rightarrow C$. Therefore, $gf:A\rightarrow C$.

According to definition, for all $c\in C$ there exists $a\in A$ such that $g(f(a))=c$.

Because $gf$ is surjective, two different values of $a$ can map the same value, hence assuming that $g(f(a_1))=g(f(a_2))$.

We know that $g$ is injective, therefore we get:

$g(f(a_1))=g(f(a_2)) \overset{def}{\Longrightarrow} f(a_1)=f(a_2)$ and thus $f$ is surjective. QED.

---

Is the proof correct? I have a strong sensation that I am missing something crucial...

Comment: Your proof is not clear : for example, I don't understand how do you derive your conclusion about the surjectivity of $f$. It seems you make a confusion between surjectivity and non-injectivity ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not even *try* to prove that $f$ is surjective. That means that, for each $b\in B$, there is a $a\in A$ such that $f(a)=b$. Where did you prove that?

If $b\in B$, then, since $g\circ f$ is surjective, there is a $a\in A$ such that $g\bigl(f(a)\bigr)=g(b)$. But then, since $g$ is injective, $f(a)=b$.

Comment: Okey, I understand it now (about time...) Thank you for your reply.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: could I ask why the surjectivity of g compose f could show that g(f(a))=g(b)? I thought it could only show that g(f(a)) = c for all c in C

Comment: If $b\in b$, $g(b)\in C$. So, since $g\circ f$ is a surjective map from $A$ to $C$, there is a $a\in A$ such $(g\circ f)(a)=g(b)$.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the clarification!